# ¿Cómo obtener el serial físico del HDD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Saludos comunidad.

En esta ocasión me han solicitado obtener un serial del disco duro del cliente (donde se ejecuta la app web).

He conseguido en la web la dll **System.Management** usando Win32_DiskDrive, sin embargo no consigo acceder a la propiedad SerialNumber como lo describe la documentación en https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx .

La sentencia que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("Win32_DiskDrive.serialnumber");
```

El error es retornado es: **"Invalid parameter"**.

De antemano agradecido por la información que puedan brindarme.

Comment: es interesante pero apoco sera posible que desde tu navegador (modo cliente) puedas obtener esa informacion?? me suena que sera del lado del servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Descarga de esta pagina:**

*Te pedira que metas tu correo*

**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx**

**1. Esto para ver el de tu disco:**

**https://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation/GetHardwareInfo_Exe.zip**

1. Lo abres como admnistrador
2. Le das a "`data storage`"
3. En la derecha saldra un select list le marcas `WIN32_DISKDRIVE`
4. Buscas `SerialNumber`
5. Te saldra: SerialNumber | 22020202020qwdqwd2020220(EJEMPLO)

**2. Usando la libreria y el codigo c#:**

**A) Podrias probar esta funcion**

```
   public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {                 
                    Console.WriteLine("SerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["SerialNumber"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Signature: {0}", queryObj["Signature"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {

            }
        }
```

**B)**  Esta segunda funcion te busca el serial usando Win32_physicalMedia

.**MODELO**

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();
    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();
    hd.Type  = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString(); 
    hdCollection.Add(hd);
   }
```

(**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx**)

.**SERIAL**

```
searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
   int i = 0;
   foreach(ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
   {
    // get the hard drive from collection
    // using index
    HardDrive hd = (HardDrive)hdCollection[i];
    // get the hardware serial no.
    if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
     hd.SerialNo = "None";
    else
     hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    ++i;
   }
```

Fuente de la 2da funcion: **http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx**

Comment: pero se supone que eso es desde c# o vb, como respondes su pregunta??

Comment: no lei bien la parte de la libreria que estaba usando :)

Comment: Eso me sirve, muchas gracias @Victor-Random .... Otra consulta por curiosidad, ¿habrá alguna manera de yo poder obtener eso de los clientes de un sitio web?

Comment: @U.Angel supongo que si, en realidad no se mucho de esas fucniones de  win32, pero creo que podrias pasar esos datos a una base de datos cuando la persona conecte

Answer (score 0):

Tan sencillo como copy paste

```
System.Management.ManagementClass theClass = new         
System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection theCollectionOfResults = 
theClass.GetInstances();

foreach(System.Management.ManagementObject currentResult in theCollectionOfResults)
{
    MessageBox.Show(currentResult["ProcessorID"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Me gusta tu ejemplo, solo que creo que en lugar del parámetro ProcessorID debe ir uno relacionado con el disco duro